# angular 2 console error Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'span'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Please don't mark this "duplicate of...". I've read the other SO posts that describe this error. I have tried those solutions.

If you look at my code below you will see I do have the `BrowserModule` imported in app.module.ts and I have `CommonModule` imported in my login-modal.component.ts, but yet this error persists for me. There is some other bug in my code that does not allow these SO solutions to work for me.

Console error is at the bottom.

**Thank you very much** for sharing your expertise. I'm stuck :-/

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { firebaseConfig } from './../environments/firebase.config';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth.service';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GameComponent } from './game/game.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { EmailComponent } from './email/email.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { MembersComponent } from './members/members.component';


@NgModule({
     declarations: [
          AppComponent,
          LoginComponent,
          EmailComponent,
          SignupComponent,
          GameComponent,
          MembersComponent,
     ],
     imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          FormsModule,
          HttpModule,
          AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
          HomeModule,
          NgbModule.forRoot(),
          routes
     ],
     providers: [AuthGuard],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/login-model.component.ts

import { NgModule, Component, Input, OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { moveIn } from '../router.animations';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login-modal',
    template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Please login...</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-container">
        <img src="assets/images/lock.svg" id="lock">

        <span class="error" *ngIf="error">{{ error }}</span>

        <button class="social-btn" (click)="loginFb()" id="fb">Login with Facebook</button><br>
        <button class="social-btn" (click)="loginGoogle()" id="google">Login with Google</button>
        <button class="social-btn" routerLink="/login-email" id="email">Email</button>

        <a routerLink="/signup" routerLinkActive="active" class="alc">No account? <strong>Create one here</strong></a>

        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
    `
})
export class LoginModalComponent {
    @Input() name;
    public error: any;

    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, private modalService: NgbModal,
        public af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {
        // this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        //     if (auth) {
        //         this.router.navigateByUrl('/members');
        //     }
        // });
    }

    public open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(this);
        modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    }

    loginFb() {
        this.af.auth.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup,
        }).then(
            (success) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }).catch(
            (err) => {
                this.error = err;
            })
    }

    loginGoogle() {
        this.af.auth.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Google,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup,
        }).then(
            (success) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }).catch(
            (err) => {
                this.error = err;
            });
    }
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [LoginModalComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgbModal,
        NgbActiveModal,
        AngularFire
    ]
})
export class LoginModalModule {
}
```

[image]

**EDIT: Made a little progress**

Ok with all of your advice, I have made some progress. The page loads without error, but now the error is @NgModule.entryComponent. I thought I knew how to fix this, but adding to entryComponents does not work.

Here is the new code...

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/home/home.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginModalComponent } from './../modal/login-modal.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public loginModal: LoginModalComponent) { }

    public showLoginModal() {
        console.log('Inside home.component.showLoginModal()');
        this.loginModal.open();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/home/home.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModalModule, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { LoginModalModule, LoginModalComponent } from './../modal/login-modal.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [LoginModalModule],
    declarations: [HomeComponent],
    providers: [NgbActiveModal, LoginModalComponent]
})
export class HomeModule {

}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/login-model.component.ts

import { NgModule, Component, Input, OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { moveIn } from '../router.animations';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngb-login-modal',
    template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Please login...</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-container">
        <img src="assets/images/lock.svg" id="lock">

        <span class="error" *ngIf="error">{{ error }}</span>

        <button class="social-btn" (click)="loginFb()" id="fb">Login with Facebook</button><br>
        <button class="social-btn" (click)="loginGoogle()" id="google">Login with Google</button>
        <button class="social-btn" routerLink="/login-email" id="email">Email</button>

        <a routerLink="/signup" routerLinkActive="active" class="alc">No account? <strong>Create one here</strong></a>

        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
    `
})
export class LoginModalComponent {
    @Input() name;
    public error: any;

    constructor(public modalService: NgbModal, public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
        public af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {
        // this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        //     if (auth) {
        //         this.router.navigateByUrl('/members');
        //     }
        // });
    }

    public open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.activeModal);
        modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    }

    loginFb() {
        this.af.auth.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup,
        }).then(
            (success) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }).catch(
            (err) => {
                this.error = err;
            })
    }

    loginGoogle() {
        this.af.auth.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Google,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup,
        }).then(
            (success) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }).catch(
            (err) => {
                this.error = err;
            });
    }
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [LoginModalComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})
export class LoginModalModule {
}
```

Here is the new @NgModule.entryComponent error in console...

[image]

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Why are you creating a module for a component? And where are you importing that Module? BrowserModule already contains CommonModule, so there is no need for the extra CommonModule.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you dont's seem to import "LoginModalModule" in your main app module.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to load a component via Angular bootstrap modal...
but I forgot to include that component in my module `declarations:[]` components list!

The component was rendered by bootstrap ng modal but `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` were failing.
Once I added the component to the module components list, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: import `CommonModule` into the module that declares the component. Make sure it's not only in an import statement, but also "imports" in the Module API (so `imports : [ ... ]` etc).

You should then be able to remove the import from the component, and all should work.

The `imports` section of the Module API is to import modules so that the declared classes in that module can use the capabilities of the that imported module.

So anyway, top of module that declares the components, do this:

```
import { CommonModule } from (etc).
```

In the Module API (in which you should have "declared" your component):

```
imports: [ CommonModule ]
```

And remove it from the component that you have importing it (and wherever else, unless you need it in another module).

Comment: The code in the question shows that already ;-) (at the bottom of the code block)

Comment: Yes but note he is also importing it in the component. I clarified the whole thing because I'm not sure whether or not that would break it (and there's no need for it).

Comment: Importing CommonModule in the app.module.ts again is completely useless if he already imports BrowserModule.

Comment: I suggested importing it in the module, and "imports" it (as you see), and removing it elsewhere. That's the only thing I can immediately see might be breaking it.

Comment: Bergben are you certain that's true?

Comment: "BrowserModule imports CommonModule and re-exports it. The net effect is that an importer of BrowserModule gets CommonModule directives automatically." see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html
Removing CommonModule might help, but adding it in app.module.ts is just a duplicate import.

Comment: That's a good one to know Bergben. Just to make sure, if you declare the component in a different module (not app), will you need CommonModule there?

Comment: AFAIK yes. The CommonModule is more for published modules, those should (unless needed) never import BrowserModule but rather CommonModule. I am curious though, could you try if it works without importing CommonModule? Like just remove CommonModule in the second module bot only import BrowserModule in the app.module.ts (if you have time)

Comment: Thank you for the comments :-) I have added LoginModalModule to the app.module.tx imports and that helped. I've been able to get the home screen to appear with no console error. However, I'm still weak on what code goes in a Module and what code goes in a Component and how to share a reusable "thing". Is that sharing a Module  that has a Component or sharing both? My issue is not truly *understanding* how to share a separate LoginModalComponent with another parent Component. I'm still trying figure this out.

Comment: Made some progress. Edited/added new code and different error to post. I think it's getting close to working :-)

Comment: I've tried adding LoginModalComponent to entryComponents in both the NgModule and in the Component decorators. Neither/either fixes the error so I think it's misleading.

Comment: Glad to be of help Locohost. It's confusing as hell to know what the module API does. I've read the docs many times, and boiled it down to: declarations = components that belong to this module (a component must belong to one, and only one, module). Imports = modules that this module's components need (and it doesn't "cascade" from a module that imports this one, e.g. app). Exports = if you want to use this module's components in templates (via "selectors"), and "provides" = injectable services need by this modules components (you do not provide components or modules).

Comment: So, ModuleOne, imports ModuleTwo. ModuleTwo has components that want to use components from ModuleOne in templates, so ModuleTwo must "imports" ModuleOne, and ModuleOne must "export" those components. If ModuleTwo needs CommonModule for its components (the ones ModuleTwo "declares") it doesn't matter if ModuleOne imports it, because imports are only applied to the declared components of a given module (no "cascading"). However, because ModuleOne exports this and that component, ModuleTwo doesn't have to import those components, just the module that declares them (ModuleOne).

Comment: Anyway yes this is one of those things that I'm betting, in the next big version of Angular, they'd say, "yeah we could make all that clearer", because even the docs say it can be confusing. Writing about it definitely helps though.

Comment: CommonModule is already exist. It can be examined for the solution of the problem. -->> https://stackoverflow.com/a/61717414/9198992