# Yet another "Can't bind to 'ngIf'"

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-module

I've looked at dozens of posts here and elsewhere with the same error message, plus the entire [modules FAQ](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq), but still haven't found a solution that works in my case. (E.g., questions 35543028, 35939950, 40426432, 40828068, 44898901, 45436552, 47660922, 50200329, 59212318...) They pointed out these things to check:

- Correct capitalization of ngIf: check
- The main module imports BrowserModule: check
- The module that creates the component imports CommonModule: N/A; the component comes from the main module, which has BrowserModule, which imports and exports CommonModule
- Add CommonModule to the main module anyway (needed at some point in the past): check
- The conditional expression is valid syntax: check

So I don't know what else might be doing this. My best guess at the moment is that the service maybe needs to provide CommonModule somehow. I tried creating a feature module for that but I took it back out when it didn't seem to help.

---

Problem.dialog.html:

```
...
<div *ngIf="data.technicalDetails">
    <h2>Technical details</h2>
    <p>{{data.technicalDetails}}</p>
</div>
...
```

Problem.service.ts:

```
export interface Result
{
    ...
    technicalDetails: string;
};

@Component({
    selector: 'problem-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'problem.dialog.html'
})
export class ProblemDialog
{
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ProblemDialog>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Result) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class ProblemService implements NextObserver<Result>, ErrorObserver<Result>, OnDestroy
{
    ...
    public next(result: Result): void
    {
        ...
        this.dialog.open(ProblemDialog, { data: result });
    }
}
```

new-db.component.ts:

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'app-new-db',
    templateUrl: './new-db.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./new-db.component.scss']
})
export class NewDbComponent
{
    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private problemService: ProblemService,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string)
    { }

    ...
    onSubmit()
    {
        ...
        this.http.post<Result>(this.baseUrl + 'api/databases/create', proto)
            .subscribe(this.problemService);
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
...
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ProblemService } from './problem/problem.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        NewDbComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
        CommonModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        ProblemService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule
...
```

---

Angular CLI 9.1.4, Node 12.14.0, OS win32 x64, Angular 9.1.4. The project builds and runs fine otherwise.

Comment: core.js:12737 Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Problem.dialog.html is a part of same module?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes--unless services create an invisible module or something. The only modules that I've explicitly declared are app.module.ts, app.server.module.ts, and app-routing.module.ts.

Comment: add ProblemDialog in declaration and entryComponents section of app.module.ts

Comment: Please remove the ProblemDialog from the service add to a separate component. Then in the app.module.ts add the component to declarations array. Also no need to add service to providers array you can use @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})  in the service.

Comment: In which module is ProblemDialog declared?

Comment: @GauravSrivastava That worked, thank you! Add an answer so I can accept it, please?

Comment: And now I see what I missed: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have ProblemDialog component in your code and you have not declared in app module, You can declare it like this:

```
...
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ProblemService } from './problem/problem.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        NewDbComponent,
        ProblemDialog //add this
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
        CommonModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        ProblemService
    ],
    entryComponents: [
      ...
      ProblemDialog //add this
    ]
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule
...
```